# Add a component to JApplet on startup

Tags: java, swing, load, japplet, jcomponent

I'm a total beginner in java and I'm coding a JApplet (that also runs outside the browser).
On my main form I want to add a QuickTable when its loaded.

Currently I have a button and when the button is pressed the QuickTable is added successfully. I copied the code behind the button into a void and tried to execute it at the end of init() but the QuickTable is not shown.

```
                    DBTable servers = new DBTable();
                    servers.setConnection(conn);
                    servers.setSelectSql("SELECT ServerID, Naam, Kost, Opslag, Paswoord from tblServers");
                    servers.createControlPanel();
                    jPanel3.add(servers);
                    servers.refresh();
```

How do I automatically execute a method after the applet is loaded?

Code behind me button is here (doesn't fit here): http://ompldr.org/vZXkycw/pasta

**GET THIS**: The snippet stops working if I remove "jButton1.setVisible(false);"
I currently use .setVisible(false) at the beginning of the method and .setVisible(true) at the end and that works fine when still working with the button. If I load the code from within init() the table isn't shown.

Comment: I answered the question, but that will obviously not solve the problem, since you already tried that.  To solve the problem, I suggest you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Which part are you not following?  I have no intention of playing 20 questions, so the more detail, the better.

Comment: @krtek pretty non answerable question ..., whats wrong with Oracle JApplet tutorial, which part(s) of isn't/aren't ...

Comment: Could you please explain me to me why? And what do you mean with the JApplet tutorial? My question isn't answered there.

Comment: @krtek as Andrew Thompson correctly commented post an SSCCE, we aren't psychics, nor can to see or read JApplets code on/from your monitor, ...

Comment: I posted the code behind the button, also found out what causes the method not to work.

Comment: sorry are you joking, which part of our comments are out of your level, sorry we are there volunters, search for page for Java supports, notice all of them are against payment

Comment: I feel as I'm being "trolled". I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. Is the code to large?

Comment: No, the code is 'too short'.  Unfortunately the SSCCE document is off-line at the moment, though if you had not been able to see the document I linked in the first comment, you should mention that rather than try to guess.

Answer (score 4):

> How do I automatically execute a method after the applet is loaded?

Call it from the (end of the) `init()` method.